# How to know mouse direction in mouseDragged in swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am looking to find the mouse direction in `mouseDragged` in `addMouseMotionListener`.

I implemented this approach in `addMouseListener` where I tried to get the (X,Y) position of the mouse in the `mousePressed` method and in the `mouseReleased` method.

I tried to calculate the corresponding direction like that:

```
   //int x = ;

   int diffX = Math.abs(e.getX() - getLastX());
   int diffY = Math.abs(e.getY() - getLastY());

   if (diffX > diffY) 
   {
     if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) 
     {
       logger.debug("No required movement ex: left/right");
     }
   } else 
   {
     if (e.getY() < getLastY()) 
     {
       if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) 
       {
         logger.debug("Upward swipe");
       }
     } else 
       if (e.getY() > getLastY()) 
       {
         if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) 
         {
           logger.debug("Downward swipe");
         }
       }
   }
   setLastX(0);
   setLastY(0);
 }
```

I am looking to do same in `mouseDragged` of `MouseMotionListener`, but have no idea how I could get the first (X,Y) coordinates here.

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I solved this problem by implementing both mousemotionlistener and mouselistener. so mousePress,mouseRelease and mouseDrag work together to find the direction of dragging. Thanks